# Start Wordpress blog feed from certain post

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, video

I have an issue that I'm hoping you could assist me with. I first want to say that I unfortunately don't know any coding beyond HTML and CSS but hopefully I can work with you guys to solve this problem.

So, my issue - I have a video blog that I'm customising a new theme for (customising the Gigawatt theme). I have 3 different sections in which I'm displaying my blog posts -

- Featured video "slider" (displays only 1 video, my latest).
- 3 column content widget. Repeating the featured video and 2 more latest videos as well as accompanying written content.
- Traditional blog section showing all posts.

This means that my latest post will show up 3 time and since they're video posts having the same video 3 times can be quite dominating. I don't want such a repetition of posts, is there any way of keeping the structure of the featured slider and 3 column widget the same, but started the blog feed from post 4? I'd ideally like to do this without constantly having to mess around with categories.

I saw - [Exclude only first post from one category from the latest posts feed, wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369735/exclude-only-first-post-from-one-category-from-the-latest-posts-feed-wordpress)

which seems to be a similar problem to mine but I didn't know whether any of it would work for mine and how to implement it. I know I would need to add it in to the theme files, but wouldn't know myself where etc.

Anybody able to offer any advice?

Here are two images displaying what I want to occur (1st) and what is occurring (2nd).

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if im understanding this correctly but here's my try:

use [wp_query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to call the posts from the fourth.

```
<?php $blog = new WP_Query( 'offset=4' ) );
if ( $blog->have_posts() ) { while ( $blog->have_posts() ) { $blog->the_post();
the_title();//Other loop stuff etc.
} } wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, I've added some images to hopefully better explain my issue. So would this be appended to an existing php document in my theme or a new php doc entirely?

Comment: you would add this as your second instance of the loop in your existing template